# CollectionViewCell effect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Are there any ideas, how to apply [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Zrl0Emt107wss23AsPYxnX7P99LuMpfd) cool effect from the new Shortcuts app for the collectionViewCells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple add the below code in your uiCollectionViewCell class and look the effect in uiCollectionView.

```
class imgcollectioncell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!


override var isHighlighted: Bool{
    didSet{
        if isHighlighted{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
            }, completion: nil)
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}  


 }
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: Yeah, it works exactly as I wanted after few changes in animate, thanks a lot! But there is an issue: when app launches or I dismiss any viewController and see the screen with this collectionView, all cells are bigger than they should be, then they decrease to the initial scale with animation. Could you help me to fix that?

Comment: you can give the layout and itemsize in collectionview when viewdidload it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> STEP-I : Return the Size of CollectionViewCell

**1.** Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate  in your viewController

**2.**  Implement the delegate method

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView,layoutcollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

  let yourPreferedWidth = self.collectionView.size.width - 20

  return CGSize(width: yourPreferedWidth , height: view.frame.width)
}
```

> STEP-II : Make the animation of cell

You can try this in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** in collectionViewDelegate.

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
}, completion: nil)
```

You can control the scalingup or scalingdown , latency to start the animation and the time of animation.

Comment: Doesn't work :( I did everything exactly as you said

Comment: I update it with animation options and if the animation doesn't work as you need you can replace it with any type of options and control the delay and scaling on x and y  Wherever suits your situation, thank you for attention.